# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'function' was never awaited self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await

I'm using below code to run a `async` function using a thread, because if I run that in `asyncio.run()` it would freeze the GUI window.

However, it returns an error: `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'transcribe' was never awaited self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs) RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`

Here is the code:

```py
async def transcribe():
        # Initializes the Deepgram SDK
        dg_client = Deepgram(DEEPGRAM_API_KEY)

        global filename
        global PATH_TO_FILE
        PATH_TO_FILE = filename

        with open(filename, 'rb') as audio:
            source = {'buffer': audio, 'mimetype': MIMETYPE}
            options = {'punctuate': True, 'language': 'en-US'}

            print('Requesting transcript...')
            print('Your file may take up to a couple minutes to process.')
            print('While you wait, did you know that Deepgram accepts over 40 audio file formats? Even MP4s.')
            print('To learn more about customizing your transcripts check out developers.deepgram.com')

            response = await dg_client.transcription.prerecorded(source, options)
            print(response)
            print(response['results']['channels'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript'])

thread = threading.Thread(
    target =  transcribe 

)

button_10 = Button(
        image=button_image_1,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=startProcessing,
        relief="flat"
    )
```

What should I do about this? Since the thread is not inside the `async` function, I can't use `await` either. I'm using Python 3.10. Thank you.

Comment: Try running a non-async function in your thread that calls `asyncio.run()` on your existing function.

Comment: It works man! Add that as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you.